# saving and restoring "brush & zoom"? (programatic zoom)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been learning `d3` through working with the [Brush & Zoom](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172) example to make a custom timeline. I would like to be able to allow the user to save "views" of the timeline: zoomed and panned to particular points, save them out to `JSON` and then restore them later.

Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction on this:

1. I'm thinking I need to save both the current `d3.event.selection` and the current `d3.event.transform`
2. serialize them to JSON
3. write a function which will take the `JSON` and recreate the selection and the transform.

Do I have the steps right? Are there any working (d3 v4) examples you can point me to? Most of the programmatic zooming examples & tutorials I've found are for earlier versions of d3 (pre v4).

---

**functions from the "Brush & Zoom" example which handle interaction:**

```
function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually an example of a programmatic zoom right in the code you are looking at:

```
svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
  .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
  .translate(-s[0], 0));
```

So, say we stored our "view" JSON in terms of zoomed to dates:

```
["2003-06-12T19:24:00.000Z","2006-05-20T19:24:00.000Z"]
```

Loading it would simply be:

```
d3.json("viewData.json", function(error, data) {
  var d = data.map(function(d){
    return new Date(d);
  })
  svg.select(".zoom")
    .transition()
    .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (x(d[1]) - x(d[0])))
      .translate(-x(d[0]), 0)
    );
});
```

Here's a running [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/zmMQBK6rEI8oB0v5pUIo?p=preview).

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

</style>
<svg width="700" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%b %Y");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var area = d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

var area2 = d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.price); });

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/8737d329-6f32-11e7-9e0d-efd5dcec6244", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  data.forEach(type);

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.price; })]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, x.range());

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);
});

function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
}

function type(d) {
  d.date = new Date(d.date);
  d.price = +d.price;
  return d;
}

d3.select('body')
  .append('button')
  .style('margin', '20px')
  .text('Load View')
  .on('click', function(){
    d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/b580e2b9-6f32-11e7-9e0d-97f11fab6446", function(error, data) {
      var d = data.map(function(d){
        return new Date(d);
      })
      svg.select(".zoom").transition().call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
        .scale(width / (x(d[1]) - x(d[0])))
        .translate(-x(d[0]), 0));
    });
  })



</script>
```

Comment: That's awesome thanks! I think that's enough to get me moving again.